# Wake from dsleep on input

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

The device I'm creating reads a liquid flow meter and logs data to a WebAPI.  Ideally it would be able to sleep in a low power state until there was activity on the sensor but I'm not sure how to work that out.  Docs say the chip will wake on a falling edge on the RST pin, but I can't have it reset every time input occurs.  Is there another way to wake it externally, without pulling reset low?  Or I guess I need a relay or SSR that directs sensor input away from RST when the chip wakes (assuming that would happen fast enough to engage the relay before it got reset again?)

Comment: I'm not an electrics guy and I'd be interested in a solution for interrupt-based deep sleep as well. All deep sleep projects I've seen so far were timer-based (current Espressif SDK dsleep is max. ~71min).

Comment: For dsleep to work GPIO16 must be connected to RST, so internally it must use GPIO16 to pull down RST when the timer expires?  Not sure how that might help me, just trying to think it through.

Comment: Reading about the SDK I noticed this function gpio_pin_wakeup_enable, which wakes it from a light sleep.  Does NodeMCU expose light sleep functionality?  If not is it possible to call the SDK functions from NodeMCU?